# Is there any way to have R script continue after receiving error messages instead of halting execution?

Tags: r, statistics

I am currently running ANOVA for a project at school that has a large number of possible runs (1400 or so) but some of them aren't able to run ANOVA in R. I wrote a script to run all the ANOVA's, but some of them will not run and the Rout file gives me 
Error in `contrasts<-`(`*tmp*`, value = "contr.treatment") : 
  contrasts can be applied only to factors with 2 or more levels
Calls: aov ... model.matrix -> model.matrix.default -> contrasts<-
Execution halted

Is there any way to write the script that will make R continue the script despite the error?

My entire script, other then the file loading, attaching, creating a sink, library loading, etc is...

```
ss107927468.model<-aov(Race.5~ss107927468, data=snp1)
summary(ss107927468.model)
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Some new answers today. Either http://stackoverflow.com/a/14612524/403310 (looped `try(eval(...))` on each expression in the result of `parse("file.R")`,  or http://stackoverflow.com/a/14613363/403310 (the `evaluate` package).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

See the function `try()` and it's help page (`?try`). You wrap your R expression in a `try()` call and if it succeeds, the resulting object contains, in this case, the fitted model. If it fails, then an object with class `"try-error"` is returned. This allows you to easily check which models worked and which didn't.

You can do the testing to decide whether to print out the summary for the model or just a failure message, e.g.:

```
ss107927468.model <- try(aov(Race.5~ss107927468, data=snp1))
if(isTRUE(all.equal(class(ss107927468.model), "try-error"))) {
    writeLines("Model failed")
} else {
    summary(ss107927468.model)
}
```

Comment: Quick update: it seems, as of 2013-02-12, that the class of a `try` object that failed is `try-error`.

Comment: @Fr. Thanks for that. I don't think this has changed and so perhaps I was confusing this with `tryCatch()`? Anyway, thanks for pointing out the issue.

Comment: `try()` is presented more or less as a simpler wrapper for `tryCatch`, so it should be the same object. But it's actually not: `x <- try(stop(e))` returns an object of class `try-error`, and `x <- tryCatch(stop(e), error = function(e) e)` returns an object of class `c("simpleError", "error",       "condition"). I'm a bit lost in all of that, to speak frankly :)

Answer (score 3):

I use `failwith` in the `plyr` package. You can use this in combination with llply and wrap your function around it.

Comment: Yep - this is how I usually approach these problems as well. The [plyr tutorial](http://had.co.nz/plyr/plyr-intro-090510.pdf) has a couple nice example using `faithwith`.