# How do you make tryCatch actually catch the error

Tags: r, error-handling, try-catch

I have to call a function that throws an error if the arguments didn't satisfy many conditions.

The conditions are so complicated that I cannot try to satisfy them 100% of the time (I would have to re-type all the conditions the function checks internally).
Instead, I should just retry calling with different arguments (as many times as necessary to fill my table).

In other languages I can write a catch block around the call.

However, in R tryCatch seems to work differently: you can give code with `finally=`, but after executing the finally-code the outer function terminates anyway.

Here is a minimal example:

```
sometimesError <- function() {
    if(runif(1)<0.1) stop("err")
    return(1)
}
fct <- function() {
    theSum <- 0
    while(theSum < 20) {
        tryCatch( theSum <- theSum + sometimesError() )
    }
    return(theSum)
}
fct()    # this should always evaluate to 20, never throw error
```

( I have read ["Is there a way to `source()` and continue after an error?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14612190/is-there-a-way-to-source-and-continue-after-an-error), and some other posts but I dont think they apply here. They achieve that the source'd code continues statement-by-statement regardless of error as if it were executing at the top level. I, on the other side, am happy with the called function terminating and it is the caller-code that should continue )

Comment: doesnt using `try(, silent = TRUE)` instead of `tryCatch` give you what you want here?

Comment: I did something like that a few days ago, I will check...

Comment: Facepalm. It works! Please create a short answer and I will accept it. Thanks!

Comment: @rawr. Facepalm. It works! Please create a short answer and I will accept it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass a function to the `error` argument of `tryCatch` to specify what should happen when there is an error.  In this case, you could just return 0 when there is an error

```
fct <- function() {
  theSum <- 0
  while(theSum < 20) {
    theSum <- theSum + tryCatch(sometimesError(), error=function(e) 0)
  }
  return(theSum)
}
```

As @rawr mentioned in the comments, you could also replace `tryCatch` with `try` in this case.

```
fct <- function() {
  theSum <- 0
  while(theSum < 20) {
    try(theSum <- theSum + sometimesError(), silent=TRUE)
  }
  return(theSum)
}
```