# How can knitr know whether the R code evaluation has error?

Tags: r, knitr

The knitr would always evaluate the R code before formatting the output, so just wondering how can I know whether the R code evaluation has error. Thanks

Comment: **knitr** uses the **evaluate** package to run each chunk, catching and handling any warnings and errors. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14613363/980833) is an old answer of mine that might help you to see how it does so.

Answer (score 1):

Basically it boils down to [three lines of code](https://github.com/r-lib/evaluate/blob/0c8005f09d76bd87366eff9c89d779fd6bfac708/R/eval.r#L189-L191) in the **evaluate** package. The key is `withCallingHandlers()`, which can be used to capture errors, messages, and warnings, etc. A minimal example:

```
withCallingHandlers(1 + 'a', error = function(e) {
  cat('An error occurred! The error object is:\n')
  str(e)
})
```

If you don't want the error to halt R, you can wrap the code in `try()`.