# How to stop a R script sourcing without throwing an error?

Tags: r, error-handling

When working in R projects, my workspace is usualy organized with several R child-files sourced by a centralized mother-file.

Basically this looks like:

### mother.r

```
print("Go")
source("child1.r")
print("Step 1 OK")
source("child2.r")
print("Step 2 OK")
```

### child1.r and child2.r

```
print("child1.r, starting")
doSomething()
doSomethingElse()
everythingIsFine = TRUE
stopifnot(everythingIsFine)
#testing
doSomeVerifications()
```

With this, I can source `mother.r` to have my study regenerated after some modifications, which will print a report.

The point is that the end of my `childX.r` is full of code that can be useful for some testings, but should not be sourced by `mother.r`. But if I use `stop()` before `doSomeVerifications()`, the mother sourcing will stop too.

**How can I stop the sourcing just before the verifications ?**

Comment: You can just change create minimal R package with your functions and use what you want instead of sourcing everything :-)

Comment: You could use a global boolean variable `runTests` and place testing lines within if statements using `runTests`. Or use `try()` within mother.r?

Comment: @PoGibas I used functions for the example, but there is actually a lot of code in each child (since there is one for package loading, data-management, testings, reporteRs output, etc).

Comment: @Teun the global variable is a good idea. If there is nothing more base R specific I will probably choose that. `try()` could also do the trick with some additional code, I have to think about it.

Comment: along the lines of the comments here, check out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14612190/is-there-a-way-to-source-and-continue-after-an-error

Comment: @chinsoon12 yes I've already seen this question, but answers are way not tidy enough. I think the purpose of the question is not the same than mine.